# convert sql code to python pandas dataframe operation

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

So I am having trouble with processing and manipulating large ammount of data.
My table 1 consist of 2 milions records for example:

```
TABLE1
ID; AGE; SEX;
1; 1; F
2; 1; F
3; 1; M
4; 2; F
4; 2; m
```

and another table with data:

```
TABLE2
TYPE, SEX, AGE_RANGE
1, F, 1-5
1, F, 6-10
1, F, 11-15
2, F, 1-5
1, M, 1-5
2, M, 1-5
```

I am creating a join:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.age, tbl2.sex, table2.type
FROM table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
WHERE 
tbl1.age >= tbl2.min_age AND tbl1.age <= tbl2.max_age AND
tbl1.sex = tbl2.sex
```

The result is a really big table (SELECT should return around 40milions rows
Then I use groupby and filter method to further filter my records. I have a problem because I get MemmoryError when running my code. I was thinking about changing csv to better accomodate pandas dataframe (to avoid using sql) 
My code example is below:

```
df_table1 = pd.read_csv(table1)
df_table2 = pd.read_csv(table2)
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

df_table1.to_sql('table1', conn, index=False)
df_table2.to_sql('table2', conn, index=False)

sql = '''SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.age, tbl2.sex, table2.type
FROM table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2
WHERE 
tbl1.age >= tbl2.min_age AND tbl1.age <= tbl2.max_age AND
tbl1.sex = tbl2.sex'''

df_filtered = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)

filter = ['sex', 'age_range', 'type']
grouped_data = df_filtered.groupby(iskanje).apply(select_random_row)
#select_random_row is my custom_made function which returns just select few rows that groupby returns
grouped_data .to_csv("result.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

The biggest problem is my sql because I get out of memmory error but even without the error it is just taking too long to load it. I was thinking about changing my csv and use exact AGE and not AGE_RANGE.... that would allow me to use pandas querying instead of sql

Comment: are your `AGE_RANGE` columns always the same, with no overlaps? i.e. `1-5, 6-10, 11-15`? but not `1-5, 3-8, 6-10` ? And can you maybe show the expected result of joining Table1 and Table2?

Comment: yes always the same with no overlaps, i was thinking about editing table1 to add another column which would tell me what is it's age_range and then use that as key when merging.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest :)

Comment: @Stev thanks for your suggestion I did just that and now I'm constantly getting MemmoryError from python :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like:

```
table1['AGE_RANGE'] = pd.cut(table1['AGE'], np.linspace(0, 80, 17))

table2['AGE_RANGE_fmt'] = pd.cut(table2['AGE_RANGE'].str.split('-').str[0].astype('int'), np.linspace(0, 80, 17))

df_filtered = table1.merge(table2, how='left', left_on=['SEX', 'AGE_RANGE'], right_on=['SEX', 'AGE_RANGE_fmt'])
```

Here I am creating a new `AGE RANGE` column in both tables and using it as a key for the merge.

Comment: I tried like you advised and I'm still getting MemmoryError. Is this Ram related or some other error? I did quite some Googling but I feel kinda lost..

Comment: Almost certainly, yes, you are running out of RAM. Using the code above (or similar) will save you having to read and write to SQL but probably won't help you on the memory side. Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Python? 32 bit processes are limited to 2GB of RAM, so maybe try upgrading to 64 bit and allocate more RAM. Open task manager and monitor your memory usage when running your code, to see what is happening. You can also Google for reducing memory usage within your dataframe( by changing data types etc), which might be beneficial for 40 million rows.

Comment: I tried installing 64bit python I'm still getting Memory Error.
Okay my idea now is to loop through every different TYPE. It will reduce ram usage, but it will make this process quite time consuming :(

Comment: Are you using an IDE (eg. Pycharm etc)? You might need to set the memory allocation for it after changing to 64 bit Python. Otherwise monitor you memory usage using task manager and confirm that you are definitely running out of total RAM.

Comment: I am using notepad++ and command line for running my script. I can confirm I get memmory error. my coworker with 16gb ram also get out of memmory error. 
I am doing group by on 20milion row dataframe. Before I split it it was 40milion

Comment: I'm not sure if it is okay to write so many comments.  
I managed to make this thing work by using FOR loop and then using MERGE and GROUPBY for every TYPE in table2. It is quite slow but it doesn't cause memmory error. Actually the most time consuming step is writting to csv now... I think I should try to take a different approach to this

Comment: Feel free to ask another question using your new code and example inputs and outputs. There are a lot of Pandas experts on here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finish my problem with quite good perfomance.

I used for loop to CYCLE through every different TYPE in df2 (it is fixed size, with 20 different types). 
Every iteration I used df.merge to merge both tables on AGE_GROUP and SEX (I added column AGE_GROUP to table1.
Then I used groupby on SEX and AGE_GROUP and custom filter on those groups. 
Whole process takes around 15minutes to complete, but atleast I don't run out of ram.